# Connecting to Oracle instance running on Docker

Tags: oracle, docker

I spent more than two days on this and I ran out of ideas and I really hope someone here will be able to help.

I am running docker on my Linux Fedora laptop.

```
[julian@julian-hp ~]$ docker -v
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

I loaded an oracle 12c image from another laptop (running Linux Ubuntu) and ran it using the following command:

```
docker run --name oracle_12c_201 -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500
-v /opt/dev/data/oracle/o12c_201_u02/:/opt/oracle/oradata
-e ORACLE_PWD=admin 12a359cd0528
```

The container gets created and is displayed as healthy when running `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                PORTS                                            NAMES
544917a88b6b        12a359cd0528        "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   2 days ago          Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5500->5500/tcp   oracle_12c_201
```

However when I try to login to my running instance I am getting `ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; logon denied` message

All of the HOW TOs I found on the internet say that if you do not specify a password when you create the container using `docker run` the the SYS password will be displayed under this line:

```
ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS, SYSTEM AND PDBADMIN:
```

There is not such a line in my logs. Note I deleted the container using all possible permutations such following internet articles such as `-e "ORACLE_PWD=admin"` or not specifying a password at running `docker run`  using `sudo` nothing worked.

When trying to change the password using below:

```
docker exec oracle_12c_201 ./setPassword.sh admin
```

It fails with the following error mesage:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container
process caused "exec: \"./setPassword.sh\": stat ./setPassword.sh:
no such file or directory": unknown
```

I ran out of ideas. I can see from the logs that the database is up and running but it is useless as long as I cannot connect to it. Note that the same image runs OK and I can connect to it without any problems on my other laptop running Linux Ubuntu. Unfortunately I no longer have the commands that I used to install oracle on that machine.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you use docker exec to run sqlplus / as sysdba as the oracle user? If you could get in using / as sysdba you can change the passwords.

Comment: can you please give me the exact command. I am quite new to docker

Comment: you can connect into container with the command `docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash` or execute the oracle login `docker exec containerName sqlplus sqlplus hr/my_hr_password`.

Comment: Charles you just saved me for another headache. Running `docker exec -it oracle_12c_201` took me inside the container as oracle user. Then `sqlplus / as sysdba` connected to the database. Once inside altering the sys user was easy. Please publish your suggestions as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Easy only if you know how to use the Alter command properly:

Enter a command similar to the following, where account is the user account to unlock and password is the new password:

SQL> ALTER USER account IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;